# Solución al "Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new' en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

He buscado bastante en la red sobre este error y veo que suele ser un problema con la configuración custom (babel, webpack etc) pero yo he creado la app de react con el *create-react-app*

El problema aparece cuando accedo a la ruta /lista y se renderiza el componente `ListaDemo`

```js
import ListaDemo from './Components/ListaDemo/ListaDemo'
import Items from './Components/Items/Items'


class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    lista: "",
    url_lista: ""
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <BrowserRouter>

        <Route path="/lista" render={ListaDemo} />

        <React.Fragment>
          <div>
            <navbar className="main-nav">
              <h2>Todo Shareable</h2>
              <h3>Share your list with friends</h3>
            </navbar>
          </div>

<div className="items-container">
          <Items />
        </div>

              <div className="go-to-list-wrapper">
                <p>Or start adding items already:</p>
                <Link to={`/lista/:${this.state.url_lista}`}> <button>Go To List</button> </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>


      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sin embargo  por ejemplo si se renderiza bien. **Estoy casi seguro que el problema está en algo con el React Router** porque si renderizo directamente `<ListaDemo />` como lo hago con `<Items />` entonces el error no aparece.

También, debo decir que si  la hago un función , en vez de una class, el problema también desaperece. Pero como necesito usar state en ese componente, y no tengo ni idea de como usar Hooks, pues realmente me viene mal tener que convertir a función y necesito que siga siendo una class.

Comment: No debería ser `<Route path="/lista" render={(props) => <ListaDemo {...props} />}/>`?

Comment: @Kiko_L Ostras..pues si. Si no te importa, me podrías decir por que hay que hacerlo así? No he usado mucho React pero recuerdo usar Route y no recuerdo tener que poner eso. Si quieres puedes contestarme en una respuesta completa y así te doy por válida la respuesta.

Comment: Esto es conocido como render props (https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) y lo que tienes que pasarle al prop `render` es una referencia a una función. Haciéndolo como lo tenías lo que le pasas es una clase y como no pones el `new` le chirría. Por cierto, te recomiendo empezar a mirar el tema de los hooks ya que es la dirección que ha tomado el equipo de React. Personalmente me parecen muy limpios (aunque al principio te dé más de un quebradero de cabeza)

Comment: Por añadir algo más... como decías, si le pasas un componente funcional en vez de un componente de clase funciona ya que ese componente ya es una función en sí.